# Regular expression for check website url

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for URL validation (in JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript)
>   [How to validate url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660209/how-to-validate-url)

I have a textbox in a form where user can enter any website url. i want to check that url, whether it is valid or not through regular expression. it will accept only like this "http://www.google.com" or "www.google.co.in".

I have using a expression like

`/((http|https|ftp):\/\/(www|WWW)|(www|WWW))\.[A-Za-z]{3}/` .

it is working but when i enter wwww.google.co.in, it says valid.

can any one help me please.

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604718/looking-for-the-url-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

- Do a request server side and check for 200 OK. Don't trust the client.

Comment: So, because you don't trust the client (you shouldn't indeed), you're willing to turn your server-side module into a DDOS relay? That code could just validate the URL's correctness instead of issuing an actual HTTP request on the client's behalf, don't you think?

Comment: It depends on your use case, actually. You may want to just check if the domain exists, or you might generate a screenshot, or you may want to fetch an RSS feed... If you are going to use the url, you might as well put in a rate limiter.

Answer (score 0):

We needed it in our project a couple of weeks ago, and I think we used this one

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

UPDATE:
I'm still working on it:

```
(ftp|http|https):\/\/([\-\w]+\.)+\w{2,3}(\/[%\-\w]+(\.\w{2,})?)*(([\w\-\.\?\\/+@&#;`~=%!]*)(\.\w{2,})?)*\/?
```

Comment: no it is not working as i want. it doesn't accept www.google.com. it only accept http://www.google.com